# Method that should create another related opportunity if the account is updated and have only one opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger

Please help me to figure out why my method is not creating the required second opportunity when the account is updated and has only one opportunity.

```
public static void missingOpp(List<Account> acctList3) {

    List<Opportunity> oppList3 = new List<Opportunity>();
    List <Account> acctsTypeProspect = new List<Account>(
    [
            SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, Type
            FROM Account
            WHERE Type = 'Prospect' AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity) AND Id IN :acctList3
    ]);
    for (Account acct : acctsTypeProspect) {
        for (Opportunity oppt : acct.Opportunities) {
            if (oppt.Name == 'ResidentialOpp') {
            }
            Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity();
            opp1.Name = 'CommercialOpp';
            opp1.AccountId = acct.Id;
            opp1.CloseDate = System.today().addMonths(1);
            opp1.StageName = 'Prospecting';
            oppList3.add(opp1);

            if (oppt.Name == 'CommercialOpp') {
            }
            Opportunity opp2 = new Opportunity();
            opp2.Name = 'ResidentialOpp';
            opp2.AccountId = acct.Id;
            opp2.CloseDate = System.today().addMonths(1);
            opp2.StageName = 'Prospecting';
            oppList3.add(opp2);
        }
        insert oppList3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are not querying any fields from the related Opportunities, that being said acct.Opportunities will be null/empty and no Opportunities will be created.

You should change your acctsTypeProspect query to:

```
List<Account> acctsTypeProspect = new List<Account>([SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, Type,
                                                     (SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunities)
                                                 FROM Account
                                                 WHERE Type = 'Prospect'
                                                     AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity)
                                                     AND Id IN :acctList3]);
```

Best regards!